# How to obtain larger output window in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have made a gui in MATLAB wherein I need the window to be fullscreen directly after I run the application. However, this does not happen so, and instead, a smaller window is generated, and as a result, the TABs that I have designed, look out of shape...
http://i42.tinypic.com/iogjfo.jpg

Suggest options as to what could be done in the code to get it to fullscreen like this:
http://i41.tinypic.com/2ufvpf6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathworks has provided some function for doing this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-3MY8PN/index.html?solution=1-3MY8PN

You can resize the window to make it the size of the screen (though the window will not be "maximized"), without having to download extra files: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-4TEZ9X/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-4TEZ9X

There are lots of matlab examples online, so searching is highly recommended.